# Another strangely "Locked" question

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

[This Question: "Can a 50mm2 cable handle 350 amps?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651563/can-a-50mm2-cable-handle-350-amps) has been locked for 7 days.

> [image]

Why?
It doesn't appear to be particularly controversial, and considering that it's only been viewed 13 times it hardly seems likely to have engendered a flame-war in the comments ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (unusual) reasons which I cannot discuss publicly, sorry. (Moderator work is ongoing in the background...)

Comment: Huh - ok ......

Comment: This is getting kinda weird though ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651630/jumper-cable-ampacity-rating - 6 views and it too is already locked ...

Comment: @brhans - Same answer, sorry. I can't explain publicly. It is more complex than it seems. There could be more or different strangeness in future, while this gets sorted out. Work is ongoing to resolve the situation. We just have to ask you to bear with us, and trust us that there is a good reason. If you don't believe that, please contact SE staff using the contact form linked at the bottom of the page. They can see exactly what is happening and while they also can't explain full details publicly, they would (I'm sure) confirm that there's a good reason for this temporary strangeness.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.